# Ideal iff closed with respect to addition and absorbs product

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

> If $A$ is a ring (with unity), prove that $J$ is an ideal of $A$ if and only if $J$ is closed with respect to addition and $J$ absorbs products in $A$.

If $J$ is an ideal of $A$, then by definition $J$ is closed with respect to addition and $J$ absorbs products in $A$.

But to show that the converse is true, we also need $a\in J\Rightarrow -a\in J$. How would we get it?

Comment: How have you had an ideal defined? If what you need to show is that it is a subgroup, remember that you have $0$ and $-1$ in the ring (also, you need to assume $J$ to be non-empty for this).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** $-a=(-1)\cdot a\,\,\,\,\,\!\!\!\!\!\!$.